# Why Json.net does not use customized IsoDateTimeConverter?

Tags: datetime, json.net, converters

I use `Json.net` to serialize my objects and I want to customize `DateTime` output:

Here is a small example:

```
[DataContract]
class x
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime datum = new DateTime(1232, 3, 23);
}

var dtc = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
dtc.DateTimeFormat = "yy";
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new x(), dtc);
```

The result is `{"datum":"1232-03-23T00:00:00"}` instead of `{"datum":"1232"}`.

This works correctly (returning `"32"`):

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DateTime(1232, 3, 23), dtc);
```

Where is the catch?

Answer (score 2):

The catch is that the converter applied via `[JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]` **supersedes** the converter passed into the serializer.  This is documented in [Serialization Attributes: JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm):

> The
>   [JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm)
>   specifies which
>   [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm)
>   is used to convert an object.
>
> The attribute can be placed on a class or a member. When placed on a
>   class, the JsonConverter specified by the attribute will be the
>   default way of serializing that class. When the attribute is on a
>   field or property, then the specified JsonConverter will always be
>   used to serialize that value.
>
> **The priority of which JsonConverter is used is member attribute, then
>   class attribute, and finally any converters passed to the
>   JsonSerializer.**

As a workaround, in the `ReadJson()` and `WriteJson()` methods of the applied converter, one could check for a relevant converter in the serializer's list of converters, and if one is found, use it.  The decorator pattern can be used to separate this logic from the underlying conversion logic.  First, introduce:

```
public class OverridableJsonConverterDecorator : JsonConverterDecorator
{
    public OverridableJsonConverterDecorator(Type jsonConverterType) : base(jsonConverterType) { }

    public OverridableJsonConverterDecorator(JsonConverter converter) : base(converter) { }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        foreach (var converter in serializer.Converters)
        {
            if (converter == this)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Skipping identical " + converter.ToString());
                continue;
            }
            if (converter.CanConvert(value.GetType()) && converter.CanWrite)
            {
                converter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        foreach (var converter in serializer.Converters)
        {
            if (converter == this)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Skipping identical " + converter.ToString());
                continue;
            }
            if (converter.CanConvert(objectType) && converter.CanRead)
            {
                return converter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
            }
        }
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}

public abstract class JsonConverterDecorator : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonConverter converter;

    public JsonConverterDecorator(Type jsonConverterType) : this((JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(jsonConverterType)) { }

    public JsonConverterDecorator(JsonConverter converter)
    {
        if (converter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return converter.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return converter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        converter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return converter.CanRead; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return converter.CanWrite; } }
}
```

Then, apply the decorator on top of `IsoDateTimeConverter` as follows:

```
[DataContract]
class x
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OverridableJsonConverterDecorator), typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime datum = new DateTime(1232, 3, 23);
}
```

Now the statically applied converter will be superseded as required.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGRGUE).

Note that, for this specific test case, as of [Json.NET 4.5.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.5.1) dates are serialized in ISO by default and `IsoDateTimeConverter` is no longer required.  Forcing dates to be serialized in a specific format can be accomplished by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm):

```
[DataContract]
class x
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime datum = new DateTime(1232, 3, 23);
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yy" };
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new x(), settings);
Console.WriteLine(json1); // Prints {"datum":"32"}

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new x());
Console.WriteLine(json2); // Prints {"datum":"1232-03-23T00:00:00"}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aJXbMw).  Nevertheless the general question deserves an answer.