# Newtonsoft Deserialize ignore/override JsonConverters

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Is it possible to ignore JsonConverters within DeserializationSettings or perhaps somewhere else which I'm not yet aware of?

I'm having the following problem:

Model A needs to be deserialized based on different requirements. For scenario one it's ok to just keep the default newtonsoft behaviour. However, for the second scenario, its required to convert some of the values to different types. This we have done using JsonConverters.

The second scenario is working fine. We haven't explicitly specified that the converters need to be used. Adding the property decoration was enough to get it to work. The problem is that this also affects our first scenario which is not receiving incorrect data based on alterations of the converter.

What are possible ways of resolving the issue, preferably not having to expose a different object and mapping values? Having separate DeserializationSettings setting would be possible, but can't find the option to override the converter.

Comment: You want something like `OverridableJsonConverterDecorator` from [Why Json.net does not use customized IsoDateTimeConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384132/3744182)?

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I've basically created a new constructor for all custom JsonConverters and passing in instructions regarding behaviour.